# Represent data across multiple categories and sub categories

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data, barplot

The data contain category and sub-category distributions.

The categories are topics in a quiz such as: Music, Sports, Business.

Each category has three levels to choose from: Basic, Standard and Advanced.

For example: A user might take a quiz on Music across different levels. Say the number of questions attempted is 100. The user would have answered them across levels. 40 for basic, 40 for standard and 20 for advanced. The data consist of counts of the questions attempted within each category for each user.

What is the best way to represent these data on a graph? Each graph would contain up to 5 main categories.

Comment: It is difficult to understand this description.  Could you perhaps post a simple example of your dataset?  And please clarify what you mean by "represent": does that mean a logical file format, a graphical visualization, a statistical summary, or perhaps something else?  What is the intended purpose of this representation?

Comment: Hey, updated the question

Comment: Thanks.  But what are the data?  The quiz answers?  Scores and subscores?  Counts of questions attempted?  I notice your edit does not address the last two questions I asked in my previous comment--please clarify those points, too.

Comment: Count of questions attempted.

Comment: Are you thinking about a graph like a report card for each student? Or are you thinking of visualizing a lot of students on a graph? If it's the latter, how many?

Comment: Kind of. However the graph will only be there for one 'student' or 'user'. It will go up on their profile page, each user has their own set of analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain all have a base of 100, a stacked bar chart may be suitable.

[image]